# 1960s French (?) novel about two couples in a machine that burrows into the earth

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

This could be a children's/YA book as I read it (from local library) around age 10, which would be early 70s. Details are sketchy but I remember it as being about two French couples and one of the protagonists has built a vehicle (called, I think, something like the Tortu or Tortue) that can burrow underground. There's one scene I recall where one of the women starts smashing up the controls of the machine.

Comment: This is a good description but can you take a look over [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Comment: If the protagonists are french, look up Barjavel's bibliography. He's a very prolific sh french writer from the 60s-70s. I didn't read them all, so I can't give you a more precise answer

Comment: Thanks both – unfortunately I really can't remember anything else about the book. I've had a look at Barjavel's oeuvre and none quite fits the description as far as I can see, although his work looks intriguing!